# Convert PDF images to video?

Tags: pdf, video, images, media-converter, gif

I have a collection (hundreds) of PDF files each containing an image. I'd like to combine the images into a GIF or video format, basically displaying them one after another at some chosen framer rate.

Obviously this can be done by converting the images to PNG or something, and then using any video editor.

But is there a software that works directly on the PDFs?

This would both spare me an extra step of converting them to PNG, and it would hopefully also be of a higher quality since PDF images are of a higher quality than PNG.

Comment: Do you really need a video or gif file? With Adobe Acrobat you can create pdf slide shows. By the way, png supports lossless data compression. So you will lose the most quality when converting to a video file (unless the storage doesn't matter)